# Send object and list of image to server in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I'm using Reactjs in frontend.

I've set the profilePicture to state with this code

```
    handleImageChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            this.setState({
                profilePicture: e.target.result //don't know how it is working 
            });
        }.bind(this);
    }
```

and I can preview the image file:

```
<img src={this.state.profilePicture} alt="img"/>
```

**I want to send these data to server:**

```
data = {
    'profilePicture': anImageFile,//this.state.profilePicture
    'photos': [anotherImage, anotherImage2, anotherImage3],
    'personal_info': {
        'name': 'User Name',
        'anyList': [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

Can I do it using fetch?

Comment: If `this.state.profilePicture` is just a data url (like `data:image/png,...`) you can just send that as the profile picture in the request.

Comment: It converted to base64 (like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...`) and the url is too long.

Comment: is it safe to decode the base64 to image file in backend(Django)?

Comment: Too long in what way? Is the server blocking the request? A lot of servers are configured to block requests that are larger than 2-5MB.

Comment: Re: decoding -- yes it's safe

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do like this:

```
handleImageChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({profilePicture: event.target.files[0]});
    }
```

Render Func

```
<img src={URL.createObjectURL(this.state.profilePicture)} alt="img"/>
```

And send data object as it is